# Standard error and explanatory (independent) variables

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

Can explanatory variables determine standard error of the intercept and the coefficients in a least squares regression? if we have more explanatory variables, standard error is going to be small?

Comment: The standard error of what?

Comment: thank you for the comment. i fitting two multiple regression models and comparing the results. for the first multiple regression model i have 5 explanatory variables and one dependent variable, the result also give me the estimated value, p-value and standard error. for the second multiple regression i used the same variables but here i add two additional significant explanatory variables and i get slightly different results and smaller standard error actually it is obvious to get different results since there is aditional explanatory variables.

Comment: My question is if we have more explanatory variables in the model does it mean the standard error is going to be smaller every time?

Comment: You didn't answer my question. Standard error of what?

Comment: Standard error of the intercept and the coefficients(explanatory variables).

Answer (score 1):

If the independent variables are uncorrelated, the SEs are not affected, e.g. R code:

```
set.seed(1234)  #Sets a random number seed

x1 <- rnorm(100)  #Random noise
x2 <- rnorm(100)
x3 <- rnorm(100)

y1 <- x1 + x2 + rnorm(100, 0, 3)  #Only x1 and x2 involved
m1 <- lm(y1~x1+x2)
summary(m1)
m2 <- lm(y1~x1 + x2 + x3) #x3 not involved
summary(m2) #SEs almost identical for intercept, x1, x2

y2 <- x1 + x2 + x3 + rnorm(100,0,3)
m3 <- lm(y2~x1+x2)
summary(m3)
m4 <- lm(y2~x1+x2+x3)
summary(m4)
```

But, in observational studies, the variables usually are at least a little correlated (and sometimes quite correlated) and here, the SEs are affected:

```
x4 <- rnorm(100)
x5 <- x4 + rnorm(100,0,5)
x6 <- x5 + rnorm(100,0,5)
y3 <- x4 + x5 + x6 + rnorm(100,0,3)
m5 <- lm(y3~x4+x5)
summary(m5)
m6 <- lm(y3~x4+x5+x6)
summary(m6)
```